# how to change cell reference value on weekly basis or daily basis automatically without manually changing the cell reference

Tags: google-sheets

I have a date range on the basis of Week1, week2,week3 and so on, This wwekly range is starting from 2022 week1 to 2023 week52. Now I want to have a variable or cell reference which need to change every week. For example right now I am in week 25 so cell reference need to be 25 week then next week is week 26 then cell reference need to change automatically into week 26.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())&" Week"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this for get data from

sheet: week
column: A
row: weeknumber (auto)

```
=indirect( "week!" & "A" & ISOWEEKNUM(NOW()) )
```